# How to save date to SQL SERVER from textbox using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to save the date of LeaveFrom and LeaveTo. I have tried this coding below. But it says that **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

```
string leavefrom = datepicker1.Text;
DateTime lFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(leavefrom); //error occurs here

string leaveto = datepicker2.Text;
DateTime lTo = Convert.ToDateTime(leaveto);
```

Comment: Which line gives you this error? You need to remember to state that in your question. You also need to describe what the actual values of any inputs are, and for this particular problem you need to tell us the current culture your application is running with.

Comment: @mason this part  DateTime lFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(leavefrom);

Comment: You need to edit that information (and the rest of what I asked for) into your question. And you don't need the rest of the code. Your issue has nothing to do with SQL Server. You simply don't know how to parse a string to a DateTime properly.

Comment: Different users in different countries will use *different* formats. `DateTime.Parse` (and the less suitable `Convert.ToDateTime`) will use the current thread's CultureInfo which is affected by the *browser's* language choices and configuration settings. Many sites allow users to select a locale/date format in their user settings. To avoid all this use a either a server-side DatePicker control or a date picker in Javascript, eg JQuery's [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: @MickeyF you'll have to decide  *how* you want to handle locales and dates first. Hard-code a locale for the entire site or page? Depend on the user's browser settings, although that's what caused the issue here? Allow the user to specify the locale in their profile? Even with a datepicker control, you need to know which format to use

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the line that throws that error is between LINE 1 and LINE 3 wherein the conversion takes place.

Instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime()` function to convert the date, use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) wherein it allows you specify the format set within the datepicker control.

Assuming the format set in datepicker is `dd MMM yyyy` (eg. `15 Feb 2018`). You can simply specify it in the function's parameter:

```
string leavefrom = datepicker1.Text;
DateTime lFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(leavefrom, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: simply explain why. what is the format of `datepicker1.Text`?

Comment: it says String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @MickeyF I know that is the error. What I am asking is the format set in datepicker control.

Comment: then use that format in the parameter - `DateTime.ParseExact(leavefrom, "dd/MM/yyyy", ....` . `MM` is month while `mm` is minute

Comment: @JohnWoo if the OP is going to hard-code the format, might as well set the locale in web.config

Answer (score -1):

As @john mentioned use `DateTime.ParseExtract()` since you have not mentioned the format of date in String i can't not point you towards exact format but using `ParseExtract`you can specify format like

```
DateTime.ParseExact(leavefrom, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope this helps.